# "no matching host key type found" Host key type missmatch on similar OpenSSH version

Tags: ssh, openssh

I recently setup a new server with Debian Bookworm and left everything default on the SSH server config. `ssh -V` on the servers returns `OpenSSH_9.2p1`

When connecting with ssh, I get an error: `no matching host key type found. Their offer: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519`.
This happens from the client versions `OpenSSH_9.2p1` (also a recent install with the same image), `OpenSSH_9.5p1` (Archlinux) and `OpenSSH_7.9p1` (older server on Debian 10).

Adding the argument `-o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-ed25519` to the ssh command allows to connect but it makes other operations that rely on ssh more complicated.

I am trying to understand how two fairly recent version of ssh can have such a missmatch. I looked at the recent changelogs of OpenSSH but didn't find anything related to removing support for host key type.

PS: the server is behind a router with port forwarding, I don't suspect it changes anything.